# Change the background color of angular-material switch without loosing ripple effect

Tags: angular-material

How can I change the color of angular-material's switch button without loosing the ripple effect?

Please see code pen here: http://codepen.io/shyambhiogade/pen/LpNGBP

I have changed the color to `#03A9F4` and now the ripple effect is not working properly...

Code below:

```
<div class="inset switchdemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="SwitchDemoCtrl" ng-app="MyApp">
  <md-switch class="md-primary" md-no-ink="" aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="data.cb5">
    Switch (md-primary): No Ink
  </md-switch>
</div>
```

Comment: just remove "md-no-ink" attribute from md-button, and change it to <md-switch class="md-primary" aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="data.cb5">

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `$mdThemingProvider` provider to modify elements style.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FRwd2fmmn0byBVUKYKi9?p=preview

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial'], function($mdThemingProvider) {
  var blueTheme = $mdThemingProvider.theme('blueTheme', 'default');
  var bluePalette = $mdThemingProvider.extendPalette('blue', {
    '500': '#03A9F4'
  });
  $mdThemingProvider.definePalette('bluePalette', bluePalette);
  blueTheme.primaryPalette('bluePalette');
})

.controller('SwitchDemoCtrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css">
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" md-theme="blueTheme" ng-controller="SwitchDemoCtrl">
   <div class="inset switchdemoBasicUsage">
  
  <md-switch class="md-primary" md-no-ink="" aria-label="Switch No Ink" ng-model="data.cb5">
    Switch (md-primary): No Ink
  </md-switch>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this seems to be correct way of doing the changes but ripple effect is missing, can you fix that and i will mark it as answer..thanks